# Using GPU takes even longer time for broadcasting in PyTorch

Tags: gpu, pytorch

```
print("CUDA available: ", torch.cuda.is_available())
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

CUDA available:  True

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]).to(device)
y = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
```

```
%%timeit -n 10000
z = x + 1
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop

```
%%timeit -n 10000
z = y + 1
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 5.19 µs per loop

Comment: Probably the overhead of communicating with the GPU is greater than the computational benefit for such a small problem. Try something like `x = torch.randn(500,500)` with `z = torch.mm(x,x)` and you'll probably see something different.

Comment: Remember, GPUs are not optimized for computing a few elements; they're optimized for massive data parallelization. Your device may have thousands of threads simply sitting idle because you only requested computation on a few elements